# Compose two routes into one

Tags: akka, akka-http

Let's consider a simplified example.

```
def routes: Route = {
  pathPrefix("parent" / IntNumber) { (id) =>
    get {
      complete(id)
    } ~
    pathPrefix("child") { // this would be in separate file
      get {
        complete(s"parent/$id/child")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I need is to put

```
def childRoutes: Route = {
  pathPrefix("child") {
    get {
      complete(s"parent/$id/child")
    }
  }
}
```

into a separate file and compose it into a parent route, but I have no idea how to propagate the variable `id` from the parent route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Routes are Functions**

One thing to remember when working with akka-http is that a `Route` is just a function, [from the documentation](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/server/index.html#Route=akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]):

```
type Route = (RequestContext) ⇒ Future[RouteResult]
```

Therefore, you can create a higher-order function to instantiate the `childRoute`:

```
//Child.scala
val childRoute : (Int) => Route = 
  (id) => pathPrefix("child") {
    get {
      complete(s"parent/$id/child")
    }
  }
```

Which can now be composed with the parent:

```
//Parent.scala
val routes: Route = 
  pathPrefix("parent" / IntNumber) { (id) =>
    get{
      complete(id)
    } ~ childRoute(id)
  }
```

**Inconsistent Route**

As a side note: your child route will never be reached.  Because your are composing a `get { complete(id) }` with the child, which also has a `get`, you will always return `complete(id)`.  The `complete(s"parent/$id/child")` will never be reached by a request.